# SSRS data driven subscription email to : parameter dependent on report parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I am using visual studio 2015 to make an SSRS 2014 report.
The place I am stuck at is my email recipient is dependent on what company is selected from the SSRS report.

> Not that it should matter but my report parameters are Company 
>   (really companyID),begdat,enddate.

```
select email from users where companyid= @companyid<< which would be my selection.
```

Most examples I see have a defined list of emails or just 1 person to email. I want to send a report per company only to the users of that company aka dynamic recipient list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Set the to Address in SSRS reports Subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318484/dynamically-set-the-to-address-in-ssrs-reports-subscription)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Modify your query as: `select email, companyid from users`
2. At the next step in  select an option `Get the value from the database` for the `TO` field and set it to `email`.
3. At the next step change your company option  to `Get the value from the database` and set it to `companyid`.

Then users from company CompanyA will receive only a CompanyA report, and CompanyB - only a CompanyB report.

You could debug the subscription using temporary query with only your email:

`select email='your@email', companyid = 'CompanyAid'
 UNION ALL
 select email='your@email', companyid = 'CompanyBid'`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, would you recommend having the email and companyid  in 1 table or view?  As of right now companyid is on a seperate company table,email is on users table and  the user/company association table is a seperate 3rd table.

Comment: it's not necessary to have all the data in one table, you can write the query using JOIN similar to: `select email, companyid from users join userscompanies ON users.id = userscompanies.userid`

Comment: After many hours I finally got a query that suits my needs. Thank you!